# Java Serialization Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: not a primitive field

Tags: java, deserialization

I am getting below exception trace. Can anyone please suggest. I am doing ObjectInputStream.readObject(). It is creating problem.

```
Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
       at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: not a primitive field
       at java.lang.reflect.Field.setFField(Field.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Field.setFloat(Field.java:746)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1092)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:455)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1244)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1833)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:762)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1981)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1938)
```

Comment: can you provide code?

Comment: My code s very large. objectInputStream.readObject() is throwing an exception.

Comment: Without any significant code there is nothing to do

Comment: File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "OfflineDraft");
File files[] = path.listFiles();
billings = new ArrayList<>();
if (files != null) {
    for (File file : files) {
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        billingsfile = (BillingDetails) objectInputStream.readObject();
        billings.add(billingsfile);
        objectInputStream.close();
    }
}

Comment: objectInputStream.readObject();  is throwing the exception Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: not a primitive field

Comment: Raghu, we need to see the class for the Object type you are trying to read. Can you add the Object class to the original post?

Answer (score 0):

A field may be either of primitive or reference type. There are eight primitive types: boolean , byte , short , int , long , char , float , and double . A reference type is anything that is a direct or indirect subclass of java.lang.Object including interfaces, arrays, and enumerated types.

Probably your class contains a reference type field which is not serializable,
try to serialize all reference type fields in your class.

Comment: ArrayList<MyClass> myClass;    should MyClass also serializable? because  ArrayList is serializable.